# Python: Formatting a string to include spaces before the printed statement

Tags: python, formatting

How can I have it so that I can have 10 spaces at the start of the second half of the following print statement?

```
print("I need ten spaces", "This sentence should have ten spaces in between this and the first statement")
```

I would like it to output...

```
I need ten spaces          This sentence should have ten spaces in between this and the first statement
```

Comment: I assume there must be more to this question or you could just put `, "        ", ` in the print statement...?

Comment: What is confusing you about the documentation on Python formatting?  This is a straightforward lookup.

Comment: Have you tried anything, or done any research? This seems rather basic, to say the least.

Comment: Sorry I stepped away from this question. I have solved it myself in a different way.  ```print("%-15s%-s" % ("Game","Total Times Game Played - All Locations")) ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `sep` argument in `print`:

```
print("I need ten spaces", 
      "This sentence should have ten spaces in between this and the first statement", 
      sep=' '*10)
# I need ten spaces          This sentence should have ten spaces in between this and the first statement
```

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply spaces

```
print("I need ten spaces", " " * 8, "This sentence should have ten spaces in between this and the first statement")
```

Or something like

```
print("I need ten spaces{0}This sentence should have ten spaces in between this and the first statement".format(" "*10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Each print statement takes an optional parameter called `sep`. `sep` is by default a single space which is why, typically, there is one space between each string separated by commas. Here is how to change that to 10 spaces:

```
print("I need ten spaces", "This sentence should have ten spaces in between this and the first statement", sep="          ")
```

or more simply:

```
print("I need ten spaces", "This sentence should have ten spaces in between this and the first statement", sep=" " * 10)
```